# Connect LocalSocket to some port

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk, unix-socket

I have 2 android applications:
 1. NDK C socket server which uses UNIX domain sockets (works fine). It binded to some port.
 2. Java client which communicates with the server.
As I understand I should use LocalSocket class like in for example:
http://all4dev.blogspot.co.il/2009/02/android-localsocket-localserversocket.html
But I dont know how to connect to localhost to this specific port.
Thanks.

Comment: A LocalSocket / unix-domain socket *doesn't have* a port number, instead it has a name.

Comment: Ok, you right. I should use name.